# Erro ao usar NgModel

Tags: angular, angularjs-directives

Boa noite, devs! Estou fazendo uma aplicação de quiz com o Angular. Na página app.component.html, recebo o seguinte erro:

> "(propriedade) AppComponent.currentIndex: número Não é possível
> vincular a 'ngModel' porque não é uma propriedade conhecida de
> 'input'.ngtsc(-998002) app-routing.module.ts(9, 20): Erro no template
> do componente AppComponent."

Porém, acredito que esteja fazendo todas as importações necessárias. Segue abaixo o trecho de código que está dando erro:

```
<div class="form-check">
          <input
            mdbRadio
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            [(ngModel)]="options[this.currentIndex]" name="option1" value="a"
          />
```

Segue também o trecho onde o erro indica, no arquivo app-routing.module.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as questionData from '../assets/questoes.json';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Desde já, agredeço a ajuda!

Já tentei de tudo rsrsrs.
Tirei importações, recoloquei, dei reload no vscode e nada funciona!!!

Comment: Vc importou `FormsModule` no `AppModule`?

Comment: Onde estão declarados **options** e **currentIndex** no código?

Comment: Importei, depois percebi que era isso que faltava. Obrigada!

Answer (score -1):

A propiedade `name` do input deve ter o mesmo nome do `ngModel`, você pode escolher se quer trocar o ngModel para `option1` ou se vai trocar o name para `options`

Comment: Era isso mesmo!! Muito obrigada!!